# Delete a file without specifying the path

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename a file then delete the old one in the same file path.

I want to delete the old file whitout having to specify a path.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim src As String, dst As String, fl As String
    Dim rfl As String

    'Source directory
   src = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    'Destination directory
    dst = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    'File name
    fl = "file.mdb"

    'Rename file
    rfl = "file_OLD.mdb"

    On Error Resume Next
        FileCopy src & "\" & fl, dst & "\" & rfl
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Copy error: " & src & "\" & rfl
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

   Kill file


End Sub
```

Comment: When you rename a file, there is no old file. The old file gets renamed to the new file name. What are you looking for?

Comment: None of this makes sense. You have a path, why is it important that you don't specify a path (not to mention like @shahkalpesh says that renaming the file makes the old name go away).

Comment: Note: `FileCopy src & "\" & fl, dst & "\" & rfl` isn't **renaming** a file, it is **copying** a file - to rename it (and potentially move it) you would be saying `Name src & "\" & fl As dst & "\" & rfl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`Name src & "\" & fl As dst & "\" & rfl`

Comment: Thanks that will do but to delete a file in the current folder whiout having to specify the path (because it's always different) could help!